# Finding similar Images

Tags: image-processing, similarity, caffe

I want to find images similar to another image. So after researching i found two methods first was two represent the image by its attributes like

`length = full
 pattern = check
 color = blue`

but the limitation of this method is that I will not be able to get an exhaustive dataset with all the features marked.

The second approach I found was to extract features and do feature mapping. 
So I decided to use deep convolution neural networks with caffe so that by using any of the exsisting models I could learn the features and then perform feature matching or some other operation.  I just wanted to take a general advice what can be the other methods which are good and worth a try. And since I am just starting out with caffe so can anyone give a general guideline how to approach the problem with caffe? 
Thanks in advance

I looked at phash just was curious that it will find the images which are same like there are minor intensity variations and some other variation wiill it also work to give the same type(semantically) like for a tshirt with blue and red stripes will it give black and white stripe as similar and would it consider things like the length of shirt, collar style etc

Answer (score 4):

It's true, that it's been empirically shown, that the euclidean distance between the features extracted using ConvNets is closer for images of the same class, while farther for images of different classes - but it's important to understand what kind of similarity you're looking for.

One can define many types of similarity measures, and the type of features you use (in the case of ConvNets, the type of data it was trained on) affects the kind of similar images you'll get. For instance, maybe given an image of a dog, you want to find other pictures of dogs but not specifically that exact dog, alternatively, maybe you have a picture of a church and you want to find another image of the exact same church but from a different angle - these are two very different problems, with different methods you can use to solve them.

One particular kind of convolutional neural networks you can look at, are Siamese Network, which are built to learn similarities between two images, given a dataset of pairs of images with the labels same/not_same. You can look for implementation in Caffe for this method [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html).

A different method, is to take a ConvNet trained on ImageNet data ([see here for options](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo)), and use the python/matlab interface to classify images, and then extract the second to last layer, and use that as the representation for that image. Now you can just take the euclidean distance of those representations and this would be your similarity measure.

Unrelated to Caffe, you can also use "old school" methods of feature matching, included in open source libraries like OpenCV ([an example tutorial of such method](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html)).